# Parse following PFUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfuser

I'm trying to make a **follow action with parse** on my **ios9** project but i have a little problem when retreiving the **PFUser** from parse using objectId can anyone help me please (the problem is in adding the user ID of current user to the user followed )

```
- (IBAction)followButtonAction:(id)sender {

PFQuery * query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:_a.userId];   
NSArray *objects = [query findObjects];   
PFUser *user= objects.firstObject;

//add the user ID for the cell we are following to the array of followed items in the user class in parse
    [[PFUser currentUser] addUniqueObject:_a.userId forKey:@"followed"];
    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

//add the user ID to the user that the user followed
    [user addUniqueObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"followers"];
    [user saveInBackground];
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that you're experiencing?

Comment: when adding the current user id in the followers case i get a warning Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your question is about the long-running operation (as per your comment):

Your query is being executed on the main thread, because you called `[query findObjects]`. Use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` instead, and place all the code after that inside the callback.

Comment: thank you ! I don't have the warning anymore but still can't add the user id on the parse "followers" case

Comment: Is "followers" an array of PFUsers on Parse? If so, you add the user directly (ie. add the PFUser, not its objectId).

Comment: I can't add anything unless the user am following is the same as logged in user ! I dn't know why it worked in this case

Comment: Right. You can't arbitrarily add/change something about another user (because you could change their email or password, for example). One solution is to create a new table that tracks followers, for example. Or you could create a Cloud Code function in Parse and use the master key to make these changes.